# Why does Object (in JavaScript) have so many methods?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am new to JS (coming from C++). I am learning how objects and inheritance work in JS. So far I have seen expressions of the form `Object.<property name>` a number of times.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. As far as I understand, `Object` is a function, and can be invoked in `new Object()` to produce a blank object. `Object` has many properties. For example, a property with name `prototype`, as `Object` is a constructor. But I don't understand why `Object` has a number of methods such as `setPrototypeOf`, `getPrototypeOf`. If one wants to achieve what `Object.setPrototypeOf` and `Object.getPrototypeOf` do, why do they have to be implemented as methods of the `Object` function?

Comment: If the methods were on the prototype, they'd be visible on *all* objects, essentially breaking that property name for all objects. Having a sort of namespace for utility methods makes code more maintainable, because then there aren't any possible property name collisions.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have namespaces (or a standard library), so it uses static methods to treat objects as namespaces. Your question is, in a very real sense, like asking why `std` has so many things in it in C++. You make do with what you have to get what you need.